# PHP array diff recursively (multidimensional) only on the keys

Tags: php, arrays

I want to extract an array_diff comparing the structure and the keys of two multidimensional arrays.

Example:

```
<?php
$array_1 =
['abc'=> '',
    'def'=> ['', '', [
        'ijk' => '']
    ]
];

$array_2 =
['abc'=> '',
    'def'=> ['', '', [
        'ijK' => '']
    ]
];
```

I would like an array diff of this telling me that the key 'ijK' is not the same name that 'ijk' (or not present on the first array).

only the keys are important to me..the values are always empty.

Comment: and if key `ijK` occurs on the first array on another level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function array_key_recursive_compare($array1, $array2) {
    $diff = false;
        // Left-to-right
        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key,$array2)) {
                $diff[0][$key] = $value;
            } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                if (!is_array($array2[$key])) {
                    $diff[0][$key] = $value;
                    $diff[1][$key] = $array2[$key];
                } else {
                    $new = array_compare($value, $array2[$key]);
                    if ($new !== false) {
                        if (isset($new[0]))
                            $diff[0][$key] = $new[0];
                        if (isset($new[1]))
                            $diff[1][$key] = $new[1];
                    };
                };
            } elseif ($array2[$key] !== $value) {
                $diff[0][$key] = $value;
                $diff[1][$key] = $array2[$key];
            };
        };
        // Right-to-left
        foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key,$array1)) {
                $diff[1][$key] = $value;
            }
            // No direct comparison because matching keys were compared in the
            // left-to-right loop earlier, recursively.
        }
        return $diff;
    }
```